# Pig Latin Translator Program (English sentence input)

Tags: java, arraylist, substring

I am currently writing a Java program for AP computer science, with the goal to translate an English sentence into Pig Latin. My full program code is
http://pastebin.com/PJgpveAh

But the main issue (I believe) is the

```
    public static String pigLatSent(String sent)
{
    sent.trim();
    String finalSent="";
    ArrayList<Integer> spaceIndexes= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    spaceIndexes.add(0);
    for(int i=0;i<sent.length();i++)
    {
        if(sent.charAt(i)==' ')
        {
            spaceIndexes.add(i);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<spaceIndexes.size()-1;i+=2)
    {
        int value=spaceIndexes.get(i);
        int value1=spaceIndexes.get(i+1);
        finalSent+=pigLat(sent.substring(value, value1))+" ";
    }
    return finalSent;
}
```

Upon the input "hello how are you"
The program returns "Your translated sentence is ellohay are ay "
when it should be "Your translated sentence is "Your translated sentence is ellohay owhay areway ouyay "

There must be something wrong with the indexing of the spaces. I am having a mental block.

Comment: Pig latin seems like a more complicated answer than this. Is your CS course's definition of Pig Latin to replace all strings with `string.substring(1) + string.charAt(0) + "ay"`?

Comment: It would be easier to use `sent.split(" ")`, which splits `sent` into a `String[]` split by spaces. Even better, `sent.split("\\s+")` splits sent into a `String[]` split by any number of any type of whitespace.

Comment: There are [many other questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22pig+latin%22+java) on Stack Overflow about Pig Latin translators in Java. They may also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You are skipping every second word: `i+=2`. This is fixed by doing `i++` instead.
2. Once 1. is fixed, you are skipping the last word, because the list of indexes does not include the end of the string. This is fixed by doing `spaceIndexes.add(sent.length());` after the first loop (which is symmetrical to `spaceIndexes.add(0);` before the loop).

Then, there are a bunch of other minor problems:

- `sent.trim()` doesn't do what you expect. String is immutable in Java, so this expression returns the new trimmed string, which is just ignored. It sould be `sent = sent.trim();` (or use a different variable for the result and use it afterwards).
- The `pigLat()` function receives the words (except the first one) including the leading space, e.g. it receives the following inputs in sequence: `"hello"`, `" how"`, `" are"`, `" you"`. This must be taken care of by the `pigLat()` implementation.
- Concatenating strings in a loop is a known antipattern — see [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm). Please consider using `StringBuilder` instead.

Comment: You stole my answer; I was going to say the thing about trim ;) Have an upvote. This is a pretty thorough answer.

Comment: Yeah, the typing speed is sometimes critical on StackOverflow, I had to give up long answers many times for this reason :))